# Where (at which point in the code) does pyAMF client accept SSL certificate?

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, cherrypy, pyamf

I've set up a server listening on an SSL port. I am able to connect to it and with proper credentials I am able to access the services (echo service in the example below)

The code below works fine, but I don't understand **at which point the client accepts the certificate**

Server:

```
import os.path
import logging
import cherrypy
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.wsgi import WSGIGateway

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s'
)

def auth(username, password):
    users = {"user": "pwd"}
    if (users.has_key(username) and users[username] == password):
            return True
    return False

def echo(data):
   return data

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
            return "This is your main website"

gateway = WSGIGateway({'myservice.echo': echo,}, logger=logging, debug=True, authenticator=auth)

localDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CA = os.path.join(localDir, 'new.cert.cert')
KEY = os.path.join(localDir, 'new.cert.key')
global_conf = {'global': {'server.socket_port': 8443,
                      'environment': 'production',
                      'log.screen': True,
                      'server.ssl_certificate': CA,
                      'server.ssl_private_key': KEY}}

cherrypy.tree.graft(gateway, '/gateway/')
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), config=global_conf)
```

Client:

```
import logging
from pyamf.remoting.client import RemotingService

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s'
)

client = RemotingService('https://localhost:8443/gateway', logger=logging)
client.setCredentials('user', 'pwd')

service = client.getService('myservice')
print service.echo('Echo this')
```

Now, when I run this, it runs **OK**, the client log is below:

```
2010-01-18 00:50:56,323 INFO  [root] Connecting to https://localhost:8443/gateway
2010-01-18 00:50:56,323 DEBUG [root] Referer: None
2010-01-18 00:50:56,323 DEBUG [root] User-Agent: PyAMF/0.5.1
2010-01-18 00:50:56,323 DEBUG [root] Adding request myservice.echo('Echo this',)
2010-01-18 00:50:56,324 DEBUG [root] Executing single request: /1
2010-01-18 00:50:56,324 DEBUG [root] AMF version: 0
2010-01-18 00:50:56,324 DEBUG [root] Client type: 0
2010-01-18 00:50:56,326 DEBUG [root] Sending POST request to /gateway
2010-01-18 00:50:56,412 DEBUG [root] Waiting for response...
2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Got response status: 200
2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Content-Type: application/x-amf
2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Content-Length: 41
2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Server: PyAMF/0.5.1 Python/2.5.2
2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Read 41 bytes for the response
2010-01-18 00:50:56,468 DEBUG [root] Response: <Envelope amfVersion=0 clientType=0>
 (u'/1', <Response status=/onResult>u'Echo this'</Response>)
</Envelope>
2010-01-18 00:50:56,468 DEBUG [root] Removing request: /1
Echo this
```

The line **2010-01-18 00:50:56,467 DEBUG [root] Read 41 bytes for the response** looks suspicious, since the response is too short (the certificate is ~1K) and I'd expect the cert transfer to be in the debug log.

**Question: At which point does the client accept the certificate? Where would it be stored by default? Which config parameter sets the default location?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyAMF uses `httplib` under the hood to power the remoting requests. When connecting via `https://`, [httplib.HTTPSConnection](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection) is used as the `connection` attribute to the `RemotingService`.

It states in the docs that (in reference to HTTPSConnection):

> Note: This does not do any certificate verification

So, in answer to your question certificates are basically ignored, even if you supply `key_file`/`cert_file` arguments to `connection`.

The actual ignoring is done when the `connect` method is called - when the request is actually made to the gateway ..

> [root] Sending POST request to /gateway

The `Read 41 bytes for the response` is the unencrypted http response length.

This answer may not contain all the info you require but should go some way to explaining the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @njoyce: thanks for the explanation and for the link. This sheds some light on this issue. I am wondering if it's possible to force cert acceptance. If i try to access this gateway from a Flex app through a browser, I'd get asked to accept a certificate. By looking at RemotingService API I didn't see a way to force the python client to accept a cert. Please share your thoughts.